# Can I see list of all IP blocked by my firewall and router?

Tags: router, firewall, blocking

I am using inbuilt firewall of windows 7. ( I am also using Microsoft security essentials ). My router is Netgear WNR1000v2 . Now can I see list of all IP which are blocked by either my firewall or router? I am not asking for the list of IP which are configured to be blocked by the firewall or router instead may be a log or list of IP which were actually blocked.

Please help me, how can I see those ?

Comment: It is more likely your firewall/router block *all* IPs and have an IP whitelist.

Comment: @ta.speot.is yes that i right, but lets say 100 user tried connecting me out of those 15 were in white list so 85 will be blocked. I would like to see those 85 IP.